# Error “something” is unknown import symbol

Tags: database, bots, telegram, replit

Please tell me why I started to have this syntax error? How to fix it? Underlines in this line of code
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
“credentials” и “db” and write: “credentials” is unknown import symbol
pyright-extended
https://replit.com/@Magistrmate/dzenbot

```
import firebase_admin
import telebot
from firebase_admin import credentials, db

import script

cred = credentials.Certificate(json.loads(os.environ\['KEY'\]))

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
'databaseURL':
'https://big-signifier-398111-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
})
```

At the same time, the bot continues to work without any errors. The underscore just appeared. How to remove it?

I tried to delete the library and install it again via pip , but no result